# arguments.callee in scala.js

Tags: scala.js

I am porting this JavaScript function to Scala.js:

```
once: function (el, type, callback) {
  var typeArray = type.split(' ');
  for (var i = typeArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    el.addEventListener(typeArray[i], function(e) {
      e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
      return callback(e);
    });
  };
},
```

Here is my attempt at writing the Scala code:

```
def once(element: TopNode, tpe: String, callback: Function1[Event,Any]): Unit = {
  tpe.split(" ").foreach(item => element.addEventListener(item, (e : Event) => {
    e.target.removeEventListener(e.`type`, ?) // <-- what do I put here?
    callback(e)
  }))
}
```

How can I reference my lambda in that place holder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala.js does not have an equivalent of the `arguments.callee` of JavaScript. More generally, it does not have an equivalent of `arguments`. So a lambda cannot read a reference to itself, unless it is given to it via its captured environment. This can be achieved by storing the lambda in a `val` in the `once` method. Ideally, one would like to write this:

```
def once(element: TopNode, tpe: String,
    callback: Function1[Event,Any]): Unit = {
  val cb: js.Function1[Event, Any] = { (e: Event) =>
    e.target.removeEventListener(e.`type`, cb) // using cb here
    callback(e)
  }
  tpe.split(" ").foreach(item => element.addEventListener(item, cb))
}
```

However, this won't compile, because you cannot use a val (here `cb`) in the right-hand-side of its definition, even if that happens to be inside a lambda. Trying to do so results in the following compile error:

```
Main.scala:17: error: forward reference extends over definition of value cb
      e.target.removeEventListener(e.`type`, cb) // using cb here
```

There is a simple solution, though: use a `lazy val` instead:

```
def once(element: TopNode, tpe: String,
    callback: Function1[Event,Any]): Unit = {
  lazy val cb: js.Function1[Event, Any] = { (e: Event) =>
    e.target.removeEventListener(e.`type`, cb) // using cb here
    callback(e)
  }
  tpe.split(" ").foreach(item => element.addEventListener(item, cb))
}
```

Make sure to declare `cb` as a `js.Function1`, not a `Function1`. Otherwise `cb` itself would refer to the Scala function, but not the JS function resulting from the automatic conversion (which have different identities). You have to make sure `cb` refers to the JS function.

Fiddle: http://www.scala-js-fiddle.com/gist/2b848e2f01e7af522dc1